# Collector for GIS will not sync offline maps

Tags: arcgis-collector

We are testing collector for GIS and its proving promising however there is one major flaw i cannot figure out.

When i take a map offline and add data to it and then bring it back to the office to sync it up it runs through the process and seems to complete however when i go and check the map on arcgis online nothing shows up. Also this is bi directional, when i add data to the arcgis online map it will not sync up with the offline map. So for what ever reason the offline map will not sync up with arcgis online even though it says it does.

Any one have any thoughts? or even better a way to get the data off the ipad with out sync'ing it.

---

Feature service is hosted on premise servers not on arcgis online.

ArcGIS 10.3.1, Server 10.3.1, Collector 10.3.3,  Apple Air iOS 8.4

I was able to save the data using a script found in this thhread (https://geonet.esri.com/thread/92080) but i am still really curios as to what was happening, ie what offline maps wouldn't not sync.

Comment: how is the feature service setup? do you have Global_ID's? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Preparing_data_for_offline_use/0154000006m1000000/

Comment: @Mapperz the feature service was established in ArcMap and shared as a service to my AGS. It it is Feature Access enabled with  the ability to Create, Query, Update, Sync, Delete features. Geometry updates are allowed. The feature class has GUIDs and is versioned, the only thing it is not is that it is not enabled for archiving...which i though was not need...but i supspect i may be wrong

Comment: @Mapperz so enabled archiving on the data set and that didnt help. Now i know it says it the article that the data must be non-verisoned but IIRC versioned data worked fine in 10.3

Comment: are date values in UTC format? 2015-09-03

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what the issue was, mostly me not paying careful attention to the directions but every time i go offline to collect the data t a new version is created version XXXXXXXXXXXX and it is that version that the new data goes in to so when i go and sync it it sync that version back to the data base and then i have to reconcile and post to the version that i serving out via our server.